# Is there a way to lookup the C# alias keyword for a given special type?

Tags: roslyn, sourcegenerators

I'm writing a Roslyn Source Generator which generates code based on the members of a specified interface.

For example, given the following interface:

```cs
interface IFoo
{
    string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I want to generate (within other code) the following property:

```cs
string IFoo.Bar { get; set; }
```

So far, I'm able to generate this:

```cs
System.String IFoo.Bar { get; set; }
```

which would work, but is there a way to use the `string` keyword, given that I don't know until runtime, when I'm analysing a particular interface type, what the type will actually be?

I've got the `INamedTypeSymbol` representing the `System.String` type. Is there a way to lookup a language keyword based on this?

Comment: Are you writing `ISourceGenerator` implementation? You shouldn't, and this API will be obsolete very soon.

And if you are writing `IIncrementalGenerator` implementation, you shouldn't include symbols as part of your pipeline.

Comment: @Youssef13 i hope they don't, that `IIncrementalGenerator` stuff is hot garbage...

Comment: @PatrickBeynio Obsoletion is actually in process and **will** happen. While you can suppress the warnings, and still use `ISourceGenerator`, I advise not to. `IIncrementalGenerator` is tricky to write, but (when written properly) the performance benefits are really great.

Comment: @Youssef13 well my SG has some stuff that won't work in IGs, but it's not a pure SG anyway and now i think maybe i'm the idiot for not making it an normal analyzer... and the SG part is structured like an IG anyway...

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that `((INamedTypeSymbol)namedType).ToDisplayString()` appears to give me what I want.

Comment: note: The cast from `ITypeSymbol` to `INamedTypeSymbol` is going to fail for array (`IArrayTypeSymbol`)